# What route to use to link to resource creator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

My goal is to link the `<%= @thing.user.username %>` to the user's profile. I know it's something like:

```
<%= link_to @thing.user.username, %>
```

But what goes after the comma?

I can currently navigate to a user by going to "localhost:3000/users/UserNameHere". How do I link to that page dynamically?

Each of my `Things` has a line showing what user posted it. Here is how `Things` are displayed:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8'>
    <div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading text-center'>
      <%= image_tag @thing.image.url(:medium) %>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
    <p>
      <strong><%= @thing.title %></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= @thing.description %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= @thing.user.username %>
    </p>
    <% if @thing.user == current_user %>
      <%= link_to edit_thing_path(@thing) do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>
      <% end %>


    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my `UsersController`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Stynyl::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :things

  devise_for :users
  get '/about', to: 'pages#about'
  root 'things#index'

  get 'users/:username' => "users#show"
end
```

Here is my rake routes output:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                  things GET    /things(.:format)              things#index
                         POST   /things(.:format)              things#create
               new_thing GET    /things/new(.:format)          things#new
              edit_thing GET    /things/:id/edit(.:format)     things#edit
                   thing GET    /things/:id(.:format)          things#show
                         PATCH  /things/:id(.:format)          things#update
                         PUT    /things/:id(.:format)          things#update
                         DELETE /things/:id(.:format)          things#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               pages#about
                    root GET    /                              things#index
                         GET    /users/:username(.:format)     users#show
```

Comment: you dont have any route to show a user

Comment: @apneadiving What would I have to do to get this going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stick to REST conventions in Rails, so use resources.

Replace:

```
get 'users/:username' => "users#show"
```

with:

```
resources :users, only: [:show]
```

then:

```
<%= link_to @thing.user.username,  user_path(@thing.user.username) %>
```

or:

```
<%= link_to @thing.user.username, @thing.user %>

#and in model
def to_param
  username
end
```

And replace `params[:username]` with `params[:id]` in your action.

Comment: Getting an error with `<%= @thing.user.username, user_path(@thing.user) %>` Here is an image of the error I get. http://gyazo.com/7ba98e797933e3698f00ef0376f60d97 @apneadiving

Comment: Duh. Thanks, man. This was the most direct and successful answer I have ever received on SO.

Comment: One more question though. Since I changed the route from username to id, user profiles can now be found at localhost:3000/users/1 instead of localhost:3000/users/UserNameHere. How do I go back to using usernames? @apneadiving

Comment: It's okay. Awesome! It got the url changed, but when I click on it I get this error: http://gyazo.com/fab04ee30e52e1f4bd828560c3927632

Comment: did you do what I told: And replace params[:username] with params[:id] in your action.

Comment: Yes I did. I will update my original post with what it looks like.

Comment: replace `find_by_id` by `find_by_username`, btw, you;d rather use the `friendly_id` gem